# name: 'MissingSchemaError'

Tags: mailchimp, mongoose-schema, mailchimp-api-v3

So, I took the independent route to implementing a database into my own sign up app before i will implement the MD5 hash logic in order to use the MailChimp API. However, before I do that I need to understand a lil more about this error.

Is this error saying to add another userSchema?

current flow:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first: String,
  last: String,
  email: String
});

const User = new mongoose.model("User, userSchema");


    app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
      const newUser = new User({first: req.body.first}, req.body.last, req.body.email, function(errr, user){
        if (err) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
          } else {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
          }
        });
    });
```

Error in hyper:

```
 message: `Schema hasn't been registered for model "User, userSchema".\n` +
    'Use mongoose.model(name, schema)',
  name: 'MissingSchemaError'
```

Answer (score 0):

Per newbie learning goes  I didn't need

mongoose.model(name, schema)

afterall.  Go figure. I was getting ahead of myself. My hope is to one day not bother with frivolous questions.

Enjoy your day!